# Python 3 How to Print a Value if Xpath Element is Empty

Tags: python, xpath, printing

My code is working to print out the xpath elements on the page. There are multiple.

My question is How to print something when there is no xpath element returned I will load 20 pages, 18 of these pages will have this element, the other 2 won't

```
amount = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id[starts-with(.,"id")]]/div[1]/header/p/strong')
for elem in amount:
    print(elem.get_attribute('innerText'), end=""',', file=sys.stdout)
```

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Which parser are you using?

Comment: I'm using selenium and chrome web driver

Comment: What about printing `elem.get_text()`?

Comment: What is *Xpath element*? Which one could be empty? `amount` is an empty list or `elem.get_attribute('innerText')` returns empty string?

Comment: try get attribute "value"

Comment: @Andersson problem is xpath may not exist on all pages loaded. so looking for a way to display nothing if xpath does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid printing empty strings, you can try:

```
amount = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id[starts-with(.,"id")]]/div[1]/header/p/strong')
for elem in amount:
    text_content = elem.get_attribute('innerText')
    if text_content:
        print(text_content, end=',', file=sys.stdout)
    else:
        print("No content found")
```

If `amount` could be an empty list, then you can try:

```
amount = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id[starts-with(.,"id")]]/div[1]/header/p/strong')
if amount:
    for elem in amount:
        print(elem.get_attribute('innerText'), end=',', file=sys.stdout)
else:
    print("No elements found")
```

Comment: Thanks Andersson, that code would be OK if the xpath exists but element innerText was empty, but problem is xpath does not exist on some of the pages. So I guess I need to do if amount exist, do this, else print nothing

Comment: You you need to check `amount` before executing loop

Comment: Thanks, that does work well if that is the only xpath I'm pulling out. The problem I face with the output now is the it only shows 1 result in my output file on 1 line rather that multiple lines.

Before I would see something like this...

    ID,Name,Amount

    12345678,Name1, /no value returned as doesn't exist on this page

    23456789,Name2,36 /value returned as does exist on page


Now it shows...

    12345678,Name1,23456789,Name2,36

So may just be a formatting issue now

Comment: Sorry formatting on this site isn't displaying how I want it too!

Comment: Figured it out, was an indenting problem! Thanks for the solution @Andersson

Answer (score 0):

You could use a placeholder character (e.g. `'-'`) like this:

```
print(str(elem.get_attribute('innerText')).strip() or '-',end=""',', file=sys.stdout)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work. No placeholder character was added when element was empty

Comment: @AuthorityDomains added `.strip()` to take care of whitespaces. Does this work now?

Comment: Oh, its not working since the xpath is not there. So let me rephrase my question. If xpath is not found, can I put some placeholder text? Thanks